# Tomcat datasource specific settings do not change when modified in application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a spring boot application, I use tomcat connection pooling for DB connections. 
When I access the application, it by default creates 10 connections per login. 
I get that this is due to

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size = 10(default value)
```

I modify this property in application.properties file to make it only 5. 
But this doesn't modify anything.
Nor does this:

```
spring.datasource.max-active=5
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very silly mistake, but please check where your properties are being used. In my case I had an xml file which was providing the database details. And the ones present in application.properties were ignored.

I was changing in application.properties so obviously it had no impact.

In the end I removed the xml file to only use application.properties file and it started working.
I used:

```
 spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive= 50
 spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize= 1
 spring.datasource.tomcat.minIdle = 1
 spring.datasource.tomcat.maxIdle = 5
 spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
```

Thank you @user7294900 . I thought of cross verifying because of your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 parameters impact inital size according to [tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html):

> minIdle    (int) The minimum number of established connections that
>   should be kept in the pool at all times. The connection pool can
>   shrink below this number if validation queries fail. Default value is
>   derived from initialSize:10 (also see testWhileIdle)
>
> initialSize    (int)The initial number of connections that are created
>   when the pool is started. Default value is 10

So you need to set those 2 parameters in [PoolProperties](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolProperties.html):

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setMinIdle(5);
p.setInitialSize(5);
```

Comment: Okay, I set the properties as following:
`spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.minIdle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle=true`
But it doesnt work.. :(
The datasource has the properties as:
`defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false;`

Comment: what is your spring boot version? try spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5

Comment: Spring boot version - 1.4. I tried spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5.
It doesn't work